# How to control PWM and digital pins at the same time over ethernet in arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, pwm, ethernet, analogwrite, digitalwrite

I am using [Controllino Maxi](https://www.controllino.com/product/controllino-maxi/). It has an Arduino Uno inside it. I am trying to control the PWM pin `D0` and digital pin `R0` via `python` code. Below is the code I have upload on arduino:

`Arduino Code`:

```
#include <Ethernet.h> 
#include <EthernetUdp.h> 
#include <SPI.h> 
#include <Controllino.h>

byte mac[] ={}; 
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 0, 200); 
unsigned int localPort = 5000; 
char packetBuffer[UDP_TX_PACKET_MAX_SIZE]; 
String datReq; 
int packetSize; 
EthernetUDP Udp; 

void setup() 
{
  Ethernet.begin( mac, ip); 
  Udp.begin(localPort); //Initialize Udp
  pinMode(CONTROLLINO_D0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(CONTROLLINO_R0, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {
  packetSize =Udp.parsePacket(); //Reads the packet size
  if(packetSize>0) 
  {
    Udp.read(packetBuffer, UDP_TX_PACKET_MAX_SIZE); //Read the data request
    String datReq(packetBuffer);
    if (datReq == "R0") 
    {
      digitalWrite(CONTROLLINO_R0, HIGH);
      delay(2000);
      digitalWrite(CONTROLLINO_R0, LOW);
    }
    else 
    {
      analogWrite(CONTROLLINO_D0, datReq.toInt());
      delay(2000);
      analogWrite(CONTROLLINO_D0, 0);
    }
  }
 }
```

In above code, if I receive `R0` over ethernet, then I am turning on/off `R0` pin, else whatever PWM I am receiving, I am setting it using `analogWrite`. Below is my `python` code:

```
from socket import *
import time

address = ('192.168.0.200', 5000)  # define server IP and port ((0x12, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0xEA, 0x03))
client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)  # Set up the Socket
client_socket.settimeout(1)

data = "R0".encode("utf-8")  
client_socket.sendto(data, address)  
time.sleep(5)

data = ("{}".format(200)).encode("utf-8")  
client_socket.sendto(data, address)  
time.sleep(5)

data = ("{}".format("R0")).encode("utf-8")  
client_socket.sendto(data, address)
```

In above code, I am first sending `R0` to turn on/off `R0` and then sending `200` for PWM and then again sending `R0` to turn on/off `R0`. When tested I can see `R0` getting high and low, then I can see `200` on PWM but then again `R0` should be high/low but it stays low. If  I re run the python code, `R0` doesnt work and only PWM works. If I power off the board and power it again, then `R0` works only for first time and it didnt work in second time.

I am a bit confused at this stage. Is there any bug in my arduino code as I am not very experienced in it. Is there any way to debug it? Please help. THanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Arduino sketch is storing the received UDP packet in a `char` array
named `packetBuffer`, then converting this array to a `String` object
like this:

```cpp
String datReq(packetBuffer);
```

The problem is that this `String` constructor expects a NUL-terminated
array, and you have no guarantee that this array is NUL-terminated.

Well, actually you have this guarantee, but only at the beginning: as
the program starts, the array will be filled with zeros by the C
initialization routine. This is why the first request is correctly
processed. The second request sends a packet larger than the first one,
so the array is still NUL-terminated. On the third request, however, the
received bytes are immediately followed by the leftovers of the previous
request. In this case it is the digit `'0'`.

The simple solution is to ensure that the buffer is always properly
terminated. Start by making it wider by one byte:

```cpp
char packetBuffer[UDP_TX_PACKET_MAX_SIZE + 1]; // +1 for the '\0'
```

Then, whenever you receive a packet, add the terminating NUL character:

```cpp
Udp.read(packetBuffer, UDP_TX_PACKET_MAX_SIZE); //Read the data request
packetBuffer[packetSize] = '\0'; // properly terminate the buffer
```